# Not receiving paypal notifications through active merchant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paypal-ipn, activemerchant

I was working on an app in which I need to work with ipn, but it seems it does not work well.

I am trying to get the notification in success action and have specified the correct url in paypal sandbox.

```
def success
        topup = current_user.topups.last
        logger.debug "topup -------->"
        logger.debug topup.amount.to_i
        # raise request
        details = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.details_for(topup.express_token)
        logger.debug "details ------->"
        logger.debug details.payer_id
        # raise params[:payer_id]
        response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(topup.price_in_cents,{
          :ip               => request.remote_ip,
          :token            => topup.express_token,
          :payer_id         => details.payer_id
        })

        logger.debug "Response starts here --------->"
        logger.debug response

        if response.success?
            amount = topup.amount.to_i
            current_user.credits = current_user.credits.to_i +  amount
            current_user.save!
            flash[:success] = "Thank you for the top up"
            # @account_history = current_user.account_histories.build
            # @account_history.update_attribute(:type => "Top Up", :details => "", :amount => amount, :user_id => current_user.id)
            redirect_to current_user


            notify = Paypal::Notification.new request.raw_post

            logger.info "Notifying --------->"
            logger.info notify
            logger.info notify.status
            logger.info "Notifying 2 --------->"
            logger.info notify.acknowledge

            logger.debug notify.status

            if notify.acknowledge
                logger.debug "Notifying --------->"
                logger.debug notify.mc_gross
                logger.debug notify.txn_id
            end

        else
            redirect_to root_url
        end

    end
```

notify.acknowledge does not return anything (it is blank)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head for quite some time I was able to solve the issue. Posting my solution just in case anyone is stuck in the similar situation :-

One important thing is that IPN sends post data to the IPN listener so make sure you have a route defined for this.

I also had a `before_filter :authenticate_user!` , because of which I was getting html code 401. Had to skip before filter for notify action.

```
def pay_with_account
        topup = Topup.find(params[:id])
        response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.setup_purchase(topup.price_in_cents,{
          :ip                => request.remote_ip,
          :currency_code     => 'GBP',
          :return_url        => topups_success_url(topup),
          :notify_url        => topups_notify_url(topup),
          :cancel_return_url => topups_cancel_url(topup),
          # :allow_guest_checkout => true,
          :items => [{:name => "Topup", :quantity => 1,:description => "Top up my account", :amount => topup.price_in_cents}]
        })
        topup.update_attribute :express_token, response.token
        redirect_to EXPRESS_GATEWAY.redirect_url_for(response.token)
    end
```

This is the return url :-

```
def success
        topup = current_user.topups.last
        details = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.details_for(topup.express_token)
        response = EXPRESS_GATEWAY.purchase(topup.price_in_cents,{
          :ip               => request.remote_ip,
          :currency_code    => 'GBP',
          :token            => topup.express_token,
          :payer_id         => details.payer_id
        })

        if response.success?
            amount = topup.amount.to_i
            current_user.credits = current_user.credits.to_i +  amount
            current_user.save!
            redirect_to user_payments_path(current_user)
            flash[:success] = "Your transaction was successfully completed"
        else
            flash[:error] = "Your transaction could not be compelted"
            redirect_to user_payments_path(current_user)
        end

    end
```

This is the notify url :-

```
def notify
        notify = Paypal::Notification.new(request.raw_post) 

        if notify.acknowledge
            @account_history = topup.user.account_histories.build
            @account_history.update_attributes(:payment_type => "Top up",:status => notify.status, :amount => notify.gross)
            if params[:payer_status] == "verified"
                @account_history.update_attributes(:details => "Pay Pal #{@account_history.id}")
            elsif params[:payer_status] == "unverified"
                @account_history.update_attributes(:details => "Credit Card #{@account_history.id}")
            end
            @account_history.save
        end

         render :nothing => true
    end
```

routes :-

```
  get "topups/pay_with_account"
  get "topups/pay_without_account"
  get "topups/success"
  get "topups/cancel"
  get "topups/notify"
  post "topups/notify
```